# Finding the de Rham cohomology of an open subset of $ \Bbb{R}^{n} $ minus a point.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

**Here’s my question:**

> Let $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2} $. Suppose that $ U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{n} $ is an open set and that $ x \in U $. Then show that
>   $$
> {H_{\text{dR}}^{n - 1}}(U \setminus \{ x \}) \neq 0.
> $$

**My thoughts:**

> I was trying to use that
>   $$
>                 S
> \hookrightarrow U \setminus \{ x \}
> \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{ x \}
> $$
>   (where $ S $ is a small sphere in $ U $ centered at $ x $) should induce a homotopy equivalence, so
>   $$
>       {H_{\text{dR}}^{n - 1}}(U \setminus \{ x \})
> \cong {H_{\text{dR}}^{n - 1}}(S)
> \cong \Bbb{R}.
> $$

I get the feeling that there’s something horribly wrong with this line of thought, so I was wanting some help. I’m okay with a direct answer, as long as you think the solution alone would be illuminating.

P.S.: This is my first post. Any advice on how I could make my question better would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Use Mayer-Vietories and invariance of the cohomology by homotopy. You have to choose a ball with a point removed as one of the open sets.

Comment: Is the other set the whole space minus x?

Comment: If $ U $ is not homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, then there’s no guarantee that $ U \setminus \{ x \} $ is homotopy-equivalent to $ \mathbb{S}^{n} $.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore: But the composition of the two inclusions is a homotopy equivalence. Thus the map it induces on $n-1$th cohomology is an isomorphism; and because it factors through $H^{n-1}(U \setminus \{x\})$, this group must be nonzero. This works perfectly well and is quite clever.

Comment: @Mike: Ah, I missed that part. Thanks! I’m learning something new everyday. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're line of thought is not entirely correct. The map
$$S^{n-1}
\hookrightarrow U \setminus \{ x \}
\hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{ x \}$$ is indeed a homotopy equivalence, so the composition
$$H^{n-1}_{dR}(S^{n-1})
\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(U \setminus \{ x \})
\rightarrow H^{n-1}_{dR}(\Bbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{ x \})$$ is an isomorphism. Since $H^{n-1}_{dR}(S^{n-1})\neq0$ we get $H^{n-1}_{dR}(\Bbb{R}^{n})\neq0.$ (Otherwise the composition would not be injective.)

However, your claim $H^{n-1}_{dR}(U\backslash\{x\})\cong \mathbb{R}$ is not correct. An open annulus $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ serves as a counterexample, since it holds $H^1_{dR}(U\backslash\{x\})\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I believe you have some typos, and some places where you intended to put a $U$ \ $\{x\}$ you placed a $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I understand the argument. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're right. I did not read over my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This actually can be done by some basic advanced calculus technique. In particular the Stokes Theorem.

First by a translation and a scaling, assume that $x$ is the origin and the unit sphere $S$ is in $U$. Let

$$\eta = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1} x^i dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots dx^n,\ \ \ \ \omega = \frac{1}{r^n} \eta,$$

where $r = \sqrt{(x^1)^2 + \cdots + (x^n)^2}$ . Then one can check that $\omega$ is a closed form. One can also check that it is not exact: Indeed, $\omega = \eta$ when restricted on the unit sphere. So

$$\int_S \omega = \int_S \eta = \int_{\partial B} \eta = \int_B d\eta = n Vol(B), $$

where $B$ is the unit ball. On the other hand, if $\omega$ is exact, $\int_S\omega$ is zero by Stokes theorem again.

Thus $\omega$ is a closed but not exact $n-1$ form on $U\setminus\{0\}$. Thus $H^{n-1}_{dR} (U \setminus \{0\})$ is not zero.

Comment: I like this approach since it uses more elementary techniques. I only chose the other answer because it did a better job of helping me understand how my own reasoning was flawed. In any case, thank you for helping me understand this topic better.

Comment: @math_nix : That's fine. Actually I did not realize that you are looking for a homotopy proof when I wrote this answer.